# Active menu state in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation, blogs

I have two blog pages: other one gets all post from one category and the other gets all post from all other categories. And Im using the new menu system that was introduced in 3.0.

Now the problem is that when user is on lets say on category2 single post page, but still in the menu the category1 has active state class.

On both categories, single post uses same template (the default one).

Answer (score 0):

Well that's easy there is a nice post on that [here](http://wordpresskillertips.blogspot.com/2010/10/insert-ads-images-or-anything-in-rss.html), put this in the function.php file within your theme.

```
<?php function insertAds($content) { $content = $content.'<hr /><a href="http://www.wprecipes.com">Have you visited WpRecipes today?</a><hr />'; return $content; } add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'insertAds'); add_filter('the_content_rss', 'insertAds'); ?>
```